# Update table based on last date of previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please would you advise how I could create a column which showed a timestamp/date for each row indicating the last day of the previous month. For example:

```
Name    Surname     DOB        Timestamp
John    Smith      1970/04/20  2015/02/28
Cindy   Smith      1975/03/20  2015/02/28
```

Now this could be for 5000 people and I've just given 2 rows to show you what I mean.

```
CREATE table employees (Name NVARCHAR(30),Surname NVARCHAR (30),DOB DATETIME,Timestamp DATETIME)
```

To tackle the problem of the dates not showing hours,minutes, seconds, I am using

```
CONVERT(CHAR(10),Timestamp,113)
```

**Do you use a While loop or something to create a column which shows the same timestamp for each row?**

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to a column to you table employees, and update it's column value? Or do you want to select a computed column? It's generally a bad idea to store computed values. What happens in one week, April 1:st? Are you going to update all values then?

Comment: Imagine the table has 500 rows of employee data. I want to insert a column in the table which has a date of 28/02/2015 aligned to each row (as shown in my example) I won't update the date in the table again

Comment: What is the logic behind inserting `28/02/2015`? Is it based on any value of `DOB` column?

Comment: It's the reporting period for the previous month. Nothing to do with DOB. So in April, I will be reporting for the month of March - 2015/03/31.  So I'm just wondering how you do that. There are videos showing how you use a loop to go from 1 - 1000 (but not with dates). But in this case, the date doesn't change for each row.

Comment: So do you need to just create a column and add  the values to it? I mean if the current month is `April` then the column should be updated with last day of `March`. If the current month if '`May` then the column should update with last day of  `April`. Right?

Comment: Yes. So it's March and I am reporting for the previous month. So I want each row for each employee to have a date of 2015/02/28

Comment: If the current month is April, then the column should be updated with the last day of March -  Yes. If the month is May, then the column should update with last day of April - I don't want it to automatically update itself (at this stage). So I have inserted February's data as an excel spreadsheet into SQL Management Studio. I don't want the column date to change next month- as that data is for February. Next month, if I want to create another table for March, I will use whatever code you kindly provide. Am I making sense? sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table have records with `Timestamp` column as `NULL`. Then with the following update query will update all records with previous month's last day.

```
UPDATE employees 
SET [Timestamp] = CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))AS DATE)
WHERE [Timestamp] IS NULL
```

The inner `DATEADD` will find first day of current month and outer `DATEADD` decrements the date by one which result in previous month's last date.

When the month in `GETDATE()` is `April`, the records with `NULL` values will be updated with `31-Mar-2015`. When the `GETDATE()` becomes `May`, the records with `NULL` values will be updated with `30-Apr-2015` ie, it won't update the records which have already values or which are updated.

Comment: It works nicely when a column exists called Timestamp. So I just also do ALTER TABLE and ADD Timestamp. then I use your code. :)

Comment: Why did u unaccept the answer that had already accepted? You had mentioned **It works nicely**. What happened? @user3497385

Comment: that was unintentional my friend. What happened was I wanted to accept Gordon's answer as well and it took away the green tick for you. I have changed it back because I liked your answer the most.

Comment: Thats k. I just asked you the reason behind it :) @user3497385

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to just subtract the day of the month from the date:

```
select t.*, dateadd(day, -day(timestamp), timestamp)
from table t;
```

EDIT:  In an `update:

```
update t
    set timestamp = dateadd(day, -day(dob), dob)
```

In addition, you shouldn't use convert to remove the time component of a date, you should simply case to `date`.  If `dob` had a time component (which seems unlikely):

```
update t
    set timestamp = cast(dateadd(day, -day(dob), dob) as date)
```

Comment: Does that add a date to each row in the table?

Comment: No, it adds a column to the output result set.

Comment: The same logic can easily be put inside an `update` statement.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that is very helpful especially your comment about using convert. Much appreciated.